# How can I partially disable C4244

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

In Visual C++ 2012 the code

```
double d = 0.5;
float f = d;
int i = f;
```

issues 2 warnings for me:

```
test.cpp(26): warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
test.cpp(27): warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
```

I want to suppress the first warning which I consider spam, but keep the second warning which I consider very helpful. Is it possible to suppress the one and keep the other? Do people generally just suppress them all? We had a bad bug where we mistakenly passed a double to a float. But we tons of our math code would trigger the double->float warnings.

Comment: Without just setting warning level 2 globally, that would miss too many useful warnings.

Comment: Would a static_cast<Type>(var) work?

Comment: Basically would like to keep level 2's C4244 warning, but suppress level 3 and 4 of C4244 only, but stay at level 4 in general. Probably not possible but that's why I asked, to see there was a trick to do it.

Comment: It is a great question.   It is 4 years already, do you find a solution?

Comment: I didn't find a way to do it. I accepted the answer below which is "don't disable the warnings".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't suppress warnings that are designed to prevent potential bugs. Tell the compiler you know what you are doing instead by casting:

```
double d = 0.5;
float f = static_cast<float>(d);
int i = static_cast<int>(f);
```

Comment: Agree on the cast for float to integer. But we can't do casts on every double to float, with graphics programming and numerous API's we are throwing around tons of float/double data and we don't care if it gets truncated 99% of the time.  We could turn on the full warnings and try to root it all out, but my sense is that it's intractable, hence the question.

Comment: @Philip You can hide the conversion by making it implicit. Pass it in to parameters as `double`s that expect `int`s and it doesn't throw the warning. It may require writing a Facade for your graphics library though.